# Preserve order while converting string array into int array in hive

Tags: arrays, hive, type-conversion, hiveql, collect

I'm trying to convert a string array to int array by keeping the original order
here is a sample of what my data looks like:

```
id       attribut                       string_array
id1      attribut1, 10283:990000       ["10283","990000"]
id2      attribut2, 10283:36741000     ["10283","36741000"]
id3      attribut3, 10283:37871000     ["10283","37871000"]
id4      attribut4, 3215:90451000      ["3215","90451000"]
```

and here's how i convert the field "string_array" into an array of integers

```
select  
id, 
attribut,
string_array,
collect_list(cast(array_explode as int)),
from table
lateral view outer explode(string_array) r as array_explode
```

it gives me:

```
id       attribut                        string_array              int_array
id1      attribut1,10283:990000         ["10283","990000"]        [990000,10283]
id2      attribut2,10283:36741000       ["10283","36741000"]      [10283,36741000]
id3      attribut3,10283:37871000       ["10283","37871000"]      [37871000,10283]
id4      attribut4,3215:90451000        ["3215","90451000"]       [90451000,3215]
```

As you can see, the order in "string array" has not been preserved in "int_array" and I need it to be exactly the same as in "string_array".
anyone know how to achieve this ?

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Hive: Use posexplode, in a subquery before collect_list do distribute by id sort by position

```
select  
id, 
attribut,
string_array,
collect_list(cast(element as int)),
from
(select * 
  from table t
       lateral view outer posexplode(string_array) e as pos,element 
  distribute by t.id, attribut, string_array -- distribute by group key
  sort by pos        -- sort by initial position
) t
group by id, attribut, string_array
```

Another way is to extract substring from your attributes and split without exploding (as you asked in the comment)

```
select split(regexp_extract(attribut, '[^,]+,(.*)$',1),':')
```

Regexp '[^,]+,(.*)$' means:

`[^,]+` - not a comma 1+ times
`,`     - comma
`(.*)$`  - everything else in catpturing group 1 after comma till the end of the string

Demo:

```
select split(regexp_extract('attribut3,10283:37871000', '[^,]+,(.*)$',1),':')
```

Result:

```
["10283","37871000"]
```

Comment: Thank you for your response @leftjoin, but this doesn't work, i completely random, sometimes it keep the original order and other times not. Also as I extract the string_array field with `regex_extract` and `split` from the **attributes** field, Do you know a simpler way to do the extract into a string format instead of string array? exemple: from this value of the field **attributes** `attribut3,10283:37871000` extract `10283,37871000` instead of  `["10283","37871000"] `?

Comment: @Stella answered, you can remove split from last query to get substring `10283,37871000`. Like this: regexp_extract(attribute, '[^,]+,(.*)$',1)